# Не отрабатывает счетчик нажатий на кнопку

Tags: веб-программирование, php

Почему то останавливается счет нажатий на 1.

web server apache2
IDE NetBeans
PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.22

```
<?php
$count=0;

if(isset($_GET['plus']))
{
$count++; 
}
?>
Кнопки нажали <?=$count?> раз
<form method="post" action="?plus=<?=$count?>">
<input type="submit" value="кнопка 1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: Потому что данные у вас передаются в $_GET, а прибавляете вы переменную, которая инициализуется при каждой загрузке скрипта.

Во-первых, PHP не сохраняет свое состояние между вызовами. Т.е. при каждом запросе весь скрипт пройдет от начала до конца, и $count сначала будет **неопределен**, потом станет равным нулю, потом прибавит единицу. Каким бы он не был по окончании запроса - он снова станет нулем в следующем. Способы сохранить значения между запросами есть - это база данных, куки (cookies) и сессия.

Во-вторых, $count у вас существует отдельно от $_GET['plus']. Для работы скрипта достаточно заменить всего одну строчку:

```
if(isset($_GET['plus']))
{
    $count = ++$_GET['plus']; 
}
```

Но я хотел бы обратить внимание на то, что $_GET['plus'] в данном случае не играет вообще никакой роли, хотя вы пытаетесь передать через него данные - вы отлавливаете, по факту, само событие отправки формы, а не данные из него.

p.s. и почитайте про формы и тег input - во-первых, отправляя POST-запрос логично и оперировать данными из $_POST, во-вторых, эти данные могут прописываться куда более органично.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Как еще один вариант

```
 $p = new Persistent($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/data/vars.dat');
 echo($p->x ++);
```

https://github.com/ArtNazarov/persistent_variables